# Java, Only the first for statement works in my code

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Just started learning Java and programming in general and i need to input 50 characters and count and display vowels,consonants,numbers and special characters. After the first for statement for my Vowels it does not work properly anymore, i have no idea why it doesnt work so any hints will help thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharArray50 {
  static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main() {
    int z = 0;
    do {
      String Str50 = "";
      int Vowelsnum = 0;
      int Consonantsnum = 0;
      int Digitsnum = 0;
      int SpecialCharnum = 0;
      System.out.print("Input 50 Characters Max: ");
      Str50 = scanner.nextLine();
      Str50 = Str50.toLowerCase();
      System.out.println("Characters: " + Str50);
      System.out.print("Vowels: ");
      for (int x = 0; x < Str50.length(); x++) {
        char Char50 = Str50.charAt(x);
        if ((Char50 == 'a')
            || (Char50 == 'e')
            || (Char50 == 'i')
            || (Char50 == 'o')
            || (Char50 == 'u')) {
          Vowelsnum += 1;
          System.out.print(" " + Char50);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("\nNumber of Vowels: " + Vowelsnum);
      System.out.print("Consonants: ");
      for (int a = 0; a < Str50.length(); a++) {
        char Char50 = Str50.charAt(a);
        if ((Char50 == 'b')
            || (Char50 == 'c')
            || (Char50 == 'd')
            || (Char50 == 'f')
            || (Char50 == 'g')
            || (Char50 == 'h')
            || (Char50 == 'j')
            || (Char50 == 'k')
            || (Char50 == 'l')
            || (Char50 == 'm')
            || (Char50 == 'n')
            || (Char50 == 'p')
            || (Char50 == 'q')
            || (Char50 == 'r')
            || (Char50 == 's')
            || (Char50 == 't')
            || (Char50 == 'v')
            || (Char50 == 'w')
            || (Char50 == 'x')
            || (Char50 == 'y')
            || (Char50 == 'z'))
          ;
        {
          Consonantsnum += 1;
          System.out.print(" " + Char50);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("\nNumber of Consonants: " + Consonantsnum);
      System.out.print("Digits: ");
      for (int b = 0; b < Str50.length(); b++) {
        char Char50 = Str50.charAt(b);
        if ((Char50 == '0')
            || (Char50 == '1')
            || (Char50 == '2')
            || (Char50 == '3')
            || (Char50 == '4')
            || (Char50 == '5')
            || (Char50 == '6')
            || (Char50 == '7')
            || (Char50 == '8')
            || (Char50 == '9'))
          ;
        {
          Digitsnum += 1;
          System.out.print(" " + Char50);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("\nNumber of Digits: " + Digitsnum);
      System.out.print("Special Characters: ");
      for (int c = 0; c < Str50.length(); c++) {
        char Char50 = Str50.charAt(c);
        if ((Char50 == '~')
            || (Char50 == '`')
            || (Char50 == '!')
            || (Char50 == '@')
            || (Char50 == '#')
            || (Char50 == '$')
            || (Char50 == '%')
            || (Char50 == '^')
            || (Char50 == '&')
            || (Char50 == '*')
            || (Char50 == '(')
            || (Char50 == ')')
            || (Char50 == '-')
            || (Char50 == '_')
            || (Char50 == '+')
            || (Char50 == '=')
            || (Char50 == '{')
            || (Char50 == '}')
            || (Char50 == '[')
            || (Char50 == ']')
            || (Char50 == '|')
            || (Char50 == '/')
            || (Char50 == ':')
            || (Char50 == ';')
            || (Char50 == '"')
            || (Char50 == '<')
            || (Char50 == '>')
            || (Char50 == ',')
            || (Char50 == '.')
            || (Char50 == '?'))
          ;
        {
          SpecialCharnum += 1;
          System.out.print(" " + Char50);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("\nNumber of Special Characters: " + SpecialCharnum);
    } while (z == 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's quite a lot of code to look through here (please learn to format your code! It helps everybody who reads it, including you! It will pay dividends to learn to do it right from the start), but one thing that immediately jumps out is the `;` in the `if` statements: `if (something); { }`: remove the `;`.

Comment: Ah Thank you so much @AndyTurner! Sorry I'm new to this so I didn't even check how it was gonna come out, I seem to have not put ; on the vowels if statement but did in every other if statement. It works now.

Comment: You may like to know a trick to check if a char is in some set more concisely, e.g. for the vowels: `if ("aeiou".indexOf(Char50) >= 0) { ... }`.

Comment: Oh wow thanks that is a lot more concise, I will keep it in mind thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have semi colon after the if sentences :)